# resize wordpress site to fit computers resolution

Tags: javascript, html, resize

I have a wordpress site that is set to 970px wide and i built it on my mac that has a resolution set to 1920 X 1080 but when my client views it on his computer it cuts off some of the site. Below is a pic of what it looks like on his computer and what i want it to look like. I did some research and i found this code but it doesn't seem to work

`<script language="javascript">
    X = screen.width;
    Y = screen.height;
    window.moveTo(0,0);
    window.resizeTo(X,Y)
</script>`

I tried to explain to him that this is a variable that is hard to control since every computer could be set differently. Any Ideas or suggestions would be great.

[image: What it looks like][image: What i want it to look like]

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What do you want to do and what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly, this is a key design element that is normally done in the very first stages of making a website. a Fixed width (and if so what desired size) or a fluid (percentile) website.

You will run into no end of issues if wordpress plugin's are set to pixels, and you try to rearrange it to %'s.

The short answer to your question is that its not just as simple as bunging in one line of code which would give a variable to yoru css width for some element. Its going to be a process of testing the site against many different browser resolutions, and adjusting to suit.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

That line of code resizes the browser to match the screen size. You should still code a website for 1024x768 if you want it reachable by the widest audience. Either that or learn about fluid designs, but make sure it doesn't get too big for large screens like yours.
http://css-tricks.com/138-the-perfect-fluid-width-layout/